# Javascript: Push Json String to Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im trying to Push a valid json **string** to javascript json **object**, but every time im trying to do it like that:

```
markersData['values'] = [string];
```

the result is of markersData json object is:

```
"values":["{'latLng..."
```

instead of (Original):

```
"values":[{"latLng...
```

it take all of the json and push it as one variable (invalid json), how can i push it as a part of the original json?

any idea how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Please be very clear about the type of values you have. Provide a **complete** example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deserialise the JSON string before setting it to the property of the object:

```
markersData['values'] = [JSON.parse(yourJsonString)];
```

Comment: Thank you! thats was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you have a valid JSON. So below will show you how to create an easy JSON which will be valid for you to use

**JSON Object:**

```
var newObject = {};
newObject.Latlng = "ValueHere";

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(newObject);

// Check jsonString before you parse for pushing.
console.log(jsonString);
```

> You will need to deserialise the JSON string before setting it to the
>   property of the object

like Rory McCrossan mentions in his answer

```
jsonString[value] = [JSON.parse(jsonString)];
```

Comment: The question isn't entirely clear, but I think the OP wants the reverse of this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Cheers, I've quoted you in my answer. His question is 100% clear, but he needs advise on how to make a valid json before he can achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
markersData['values'] = [JSON.parse(string)];
```

Hope this helps.. Read more about [JSON.parse here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string first.

`JSON.parse(addstringvar);`

[Code pen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPgQdg)

```
var testObj = {};
var addString = '{"name": "test"}';
testObj.values = [JSON.parse(addString)];
```